# Read from a file into a Emacs lisp list

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have the following file `data.txt`

```
A
B
C
D
```

I would like to read the contents of this file into a Lisp `list`, like

```
(defun read-list-from-file (fn)
  (interactive)
  (list "A" "B" "C" "D"))

(defun my-read ()
  (interactive)
  (let (( mylist (read-list-from-file "data.txt")))
    (print mylist t)))
```

How can I modify `read-list-from-file` such that it returns the same list, but instead reads from the file given as input argument `fn`.. Each line in the file should be a separate item in the list..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code:

```lisp
(with-current-buffer
    (find-file-noselect "~/data.txt")
  (split-string
   (save-restriction
     (widen)
     (buffer-substring-no-properties
      (point-min)
      (point-max)))
   "\n" t))
```

### UPD:

Here's a version with `insert-file-contents`:

```lisp
(defun slurp (f)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert-file-contents f)
    (buffer-substring-no-properties
       (point-min)
       (point-max))))

(split-string
 (slurp "~/data.txt") "\n" t)
```

Comment: Note that if you have an open buffer visiting `data.txt`, and that buffer is narrowed, this function may not return everything it should.  You should wrap that call to `split-string` in a `(save-restriction (widen) ...)`.

Comment: Use `with-temp-buffer` and `insert-file-contents` instead of `with-current-buffer` and `find-file-noselect` to avoid leaving a buffer around.

Comment: buffer-string makes this easier too. you don't need to worry about property removal as there probably aren't any properties on a file you just read, or you could use insert-file-contents-literally

Answer (score 7):

Much easier, than creating a temporary buffer, is to use [`f`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el) file manipulation library's [`f-read`](https://github.com/rejeep/f.el#f-read-text-path-optional-coding) function that returns textual content of a file (default coding UTF-8). 
`f` is a third-party that you need to install from MELPA, read [Xah Lee's](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html) tutorial on how to use Emacs package management system. Then you could use either `split-string` or [`s`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) string manipulation library's [`s-split`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-split-separator-s-optional-omit-nulls) (which is a simple wrapper around the former function):

```
(s-split "\n" (f-read "~/data.txt") t) ; ("A" "B" "C" "D")
```

*Note:* third parameter to `s-split` set to `t` omits empty strings. You could use [`s-lines`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-lines-s), but as textual files on *nix systems usually contain a trailing newline, the returned list would be `("A" "B" "C" "D" "")`. You can remove the last element with [`dash`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) list manipulation library's [`butlast`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-butlast-list) function, but this works in O(n), so probably stick to `s-split`, unless you want empty lines to be preserved in the list.

Comment: Great answer, I already use s for string manipulation, and dash for everything else, nice to know that there's a nice f for file manipulation too.

Comment: FWIW, `f-read` uses basically the same approach as @abo-abo's `slurp` (i.e. creates a temp buffer): https://github.com/rejeep/f.el/blob/master/f.el#L207  It has other niceties, though.